# Can Spreadsheet::WriteExcel change the format of a cell without modifying its contents?

Tags: perl, excel, format, cpan, perl-module

In my Perl script I use the [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.37/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) module to create an Excel file. The file contains a table, the size of which is dynamic - i.e., I don't know how many rows it will have until the table is already created. I would like the last row of the table to have a slightly different format (e.g., its bottom border to be "==="). Unfortunately, I cannot apply this (different) format at the time when the row is being created, since at that time I don't know yet that it will be the last row.

So, my question is: can I change the format of an already existing cell without changing its contents? If I pass `undef` as cell value to the `$worksheet->write()` method it just overwrites the contents of the cell with a blank cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that you cannot modify the format of an already written cell in [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/). This is a planned feature for [Excel::Writer::XLSX](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Excel-Writer-XLSX/) but it isn't in place yet.

So you will need to workaround it in some way such as buffering the table data until you are ready to write it or buffering a row at a time and only writing it when you have a new row.

Or you could turn on [compatiblilty_mode()](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#compatibility_mode%28%29) and overwrite the last row with new formatted data. Note, this approach isn't recommended without compatibility_mode() since Excel will complain about duplicate and or missing data in the file.

Alternatively, setting the row format, as pointed out by @bvr, might work for you.

Comment: I do use `compatibility_mode()`. Do you mean that I should buffer the last row of the table and rewrite it again with the new format after the table is complete? No, that won't fit well with my current algorithm.

BTW, I don't want to use the `Excel::Writer::XLSX` module, since I want to create Excel97-style files, not the new format.

OK, so I'll accept that the answer to my question is "it can't be done".

Answer (score 1):

Unless your data is too big for memory, you can put your table data in an array first, then loop over the array to output. You'll have access to any element in the array to begin with, so you'll know what the last row will be and what kinds of data will be in it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the format to any row with `set_row` method without changing the data.

Comment: As far as I understand from the documentation, that would set the format of the entire row. This will look awfully ugly. I want to change the format on of a part of the row - only the part occupied by the table.